# Unable to fetch Firewall Rules via firewall-plugin API

Tags: api, firewall, opnsense

I'm having some troubles trying to fetch fw rules.
I read the dock and looked at the examples at the page https://docs.opnsense.org/development/api/plugins/firewall.html but i still have problems.
I'm trying to use the searchRule API via python, and i can't get anything back with a simple call without any attributes, here's my code

```py
import json, requests


KEY = "my_key"
SECRET = "my_secret"

url = "https://192.168.2.1/api/firewall/filter/searchRule"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(KEY, SECRET))
print(r.text)
```

result is always

```py
{"rows":[],"rowCount":0,"total":0,"current":1}
```

Well, i've tryed to add some attributes to the call, but nothing changes, notice that i setted "icmp_dummies_rule" as the rule description cause i thought taht searchPhrase matches that field (also there's no unique name filed available, as far as i can see)
I tryed:

```py
url = 'https://192.168.2.1/api/firewall/filter/searchRule?searchPhrase="icmp_dummies_rule"'
url = 'https://192.168.2.1/api/firewall/filter/searchRule?searchPhrase=icmp_dummies_rule'
url = 'https://192.168.2.1/api/firewall/filter/searchRule?current=1&searchPhrase="icmp_dummies_rule"'
url = 'https://192.168.2.1/api/firewall/filter/searchRule?current=1&searchPhrase=icmp_dummies_rule'
```

Also i can't pass any UUID cause i don't know the rule UUID (but i prefere to retrive all the rules for flexibility reason and cleaner code).

Any idea here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

notice that this behavoir IS NOT REPORTED in api doc.
Adding firewall-plugin module will add an **Automation** voice under **Firewall** section

[image]

now under **Filter** voice you can create, manage and delete rules, those rules will be availables via API queryes.

**Notice that rules added under RULE voice (as default) aren't availables via API interface**